# Not able to extract any .gz or .tar file (Mac OS X 10.5.8)

Tags: macos, archive, tar

I have Mac OS X 10.5.8. I am not able to extract `.tar` or `.tgz` files with any of the extractor utilities (Mac OS Default Archiver or WinZip or 7zip or any other, I have tried almost all possible).

Each of them give same error:

> "Unable to unarchive. (Error 32 - Broken pipe.)"

There is no problem with archived files, I can extract each of them when I use same extractors on Windows.

Would someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 9):

Does it work from a terminal for tgz files? Open a terminal and cd to the folder that has the files and try something like this:

```
tar xvzf file.tar.gz
```

Or for plain tar files:

```
tar xvf file.tar
```

Comment: I usually face the same problem and go back to terminal to extract the archives. I get this even with zipped files.

Answer (score 2):

There may be too many NUL blocks at the end of the tar file, so that the `tar` command prematurely finishes its executions (and closes its standard input) after having received two NUL blocks while the `gunzip` command is still trying to write to the pipe that now has no reader anymore (which raises an `EPIPE`error message with error number 32 for a broken pipe; for more information see: [Tar-filled pipes](http://davidben.scripts.mit.edu/blog/2010/02/28/tar-filled-pipes/)).

According to the output of [newproc.d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459493/monitor-cocoa-apps-for-execution-of-external-utilities-e-g-ffmpeg-on-mac-os) `Archive Utility.app` seems to use the following commands (Mac OS X uses `bsdtar` by default):

```
/usr/bin/gunzip -c file.tar.gz | /usr/bin/tar xf - -C dir
```

To see the number of trailing NUL blocks in the tar file use:

```
gnutar -tzf file.tar.gz -i --block-number | nl | tail -n 25
```

To extract the tar archive try:

```
# -i: ignore blocks of zeros in archive (normally mean EOF)
gnutar -i -xvf file.tar.gz
```

`.zip` files can be tested with:

```
unzip -lv file.zip
unzip -t file.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

check the directory and the path, the scipt may lead you to users/download/folders/blah

but you keep it on users/favourite/folder/blah (example) thats make the error.

Comment: Could you clarify that a bit?

Answer (score 0):

Your Hard Drive may also be running out of storage.